# Using a curl scheduled task in windows

Tags: windows-7, scheduled-tasks, curl, windows-task-scheduler

I am using the following command in a scheduled task in windows to update my IP to the free Dynamic DNS service called [EntryDNS](https://entrydns.net):

curl.exe -k -X PUT -d "" "Their url API string here"

The problem I am having is curl is opening a terminal every time the command executes. Is there a switch or way to get curl to run "silently" or in a non verbose way where a terminal will not show?

EDIT: I have tried using both -s -S switches. (-sS too)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

cURL is a console application so it *will* cause a command prompt window to show up, however briefly.

What you can do is use [Hidden Start](http://www.ntwind.com/software/hstart.html) to invoke cURL in turn:

[image: 1]

[image: 2]